# jQuery click function ul menu to exclude first ul

Tags: jquery

I had someone write this for me and went MIA and can't figure out how to tweak it myself. I am kind of new to jQuery. This is for a expandable sidebar navigation using `<ul>` and currently the whole thing is expandable and contractable on click.

I am trying to have the first Title 1 `<ul>` permanently "expanded" to show Link 1 and Link 2, but keep the jQuery work on the Title 2 (and 3, 4, 5 and so on).

How can I permanently keep the first `<ul>` open? Help is much appreciated!

```
<div class="sidebar">
<nav>
<span class="heading">Title 1</span>
<ul>
<li><a href="/firstlink">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/firstlink">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<nav>
<span class="heading">Title 2</span>
<ul>
<li><a href="/firstlink">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/firstlink">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery bit that makes it expand and contract:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery('#body .sidebar nav').click(function(){
    var the_ul = jQuery('> ul', this);
    if(the_ul){
        if (the_ul.css('display') == 'none') {
            jQuery(the_ul).slideDown('500');
        } else {
            jQuery(the_ul).slideUp('500');
        }
    };
});  
});
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.sidebar nav ul {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
$('.sidebar nav ul:eq(0)').show();

$('.sidebar nav').click(function(){
    var the_ul = $(this).find("ul");

    if(the_ul){
        if (the_ul.css('display') == 'none') {
            the_ul.slideDown('500');
        } else {
            the_ul.slideUp('500');
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NPfND/)</kbd>

Comment: i think so too. the demo is perfect. but i tried replacing my current jQuery lines (above) with yours in my .js file doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/v7JhL/1/) and remove the CSS:

```
jQuery('#body .sidebar nav:gt(0)').click(function(){
    var the_ul = jQuery('> ul', this);
    if(the_ul){
        if (the_ul.css('display') == 'none') {
            jQuery(the_ul).slideDown('500');
        } else {
            jQuery(the_ul).slideUp('500');
        }
    };
});
jQuery('.sidebar nav > ul:gt(0)').hide()
```

Comment: Thank you. But something in this is conflicting with something else on the site and triggering a multitude of alert popups.

Comment: Sorry - I had to change `#body` to body in the jsFiddle and forgot to change it back: http://jsfiddle.net/v7JhL/2/ Maybe this is the problem. Otherwise - what is in the alert popup?

Comment: It's a Shopify error that says "Received everything we ever wanted to know about ' + product.title"